# Triggers do not trigger on third party changes

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a spreadsheet that was intended to be shared with a small group of contributors, each one with a full edit permission over only one respective sheet. I built a main sheet that was supposed to compute the information passed by all the others collaborator's sheets and make an instant update in it. 
When I, as the owner, make any changes on those particular sheets, the main one works like a charm. But when someone else changes the same thing, nothing happens.

Is this something that should already be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the `onEdit` [simple event handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#Simple), which means that the script is running under the permission of who's making the edit. Therefore, if the user is not allowed to do something, the script will not be allowed either.

To fix this you should use the [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#Installable) on edit trigger instead. Just rename your `onEdit` function to something else e.g. "installableOnEdit", so it's not triggered as a simple handler, then go to the menu "Resources > Current project's triggers" and set up a trigger to run your on-edit function on Spreadsheet edit events.

By doing this, the trigger will always run under your account, which should have the required access to modify the protected sheets.